# Shortest path (point to point) in iteration, safe for the case there is no route

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, iteration, shortest-path

I am using `Network Analysis > Shortest path (point to point)` to compute the distance between two points, following a street network.

Here is the code:

```
n=0
for f1 in layer1:
     #Coordinates from first layer
     geom1 = f1.geometry()
     x1=geom1.asPoint().x()
     y1=geom1.asPoint().y()
     x1str=str(x1)
     y1str=str(y1)
     coord1= x1str+","+y1str
     
     for f2 in layer2:
         #Coordinates from the second layer
         geom2 = f2.geometry()
         x2=geom2.asPoint().x()
         y2=geom2.asPoint().y()
         x2str=str(x2)
         y2str=str(y2)
         coord2= x2str+","+y2str
         n=n+1
         n=str(n)
         

         processing.run("native:shortestpathpointtopoint", {
            'INPUT':'./Do_Straßen_EPSG 25832.shp|layername=Do_Straßen_EPSG 25832',
            'STRATEGY':0,
            'DIRECTION_FIELD':'',
            'VALUE_FORWARD':'',
            'VALUE_BACKWARD':'',
            'VALUE_BOTH':'',
            'DEFAULT_DIRECTION':2,
            'SPEED_FIELD':'',
            'DEFAULT_SPEED':50,
            'TOLERANCE':0,
            'START_POINT':''+coord1+'',
            'END_POINT':''+coord2+'',
            'OUTPUT':'./ShortPath/layer'+n+'.shp'})
         
         n=int(n)
```

In my first trial, the iteration stopped after 207 features from 1500. The error message showed me, that there was no route, so my iteration stopped.

How can I build in a safe for that case, when no route was found?

I thought of an `if` statement, but I can't imagine the expression.

Comment: Maybe a try-catch structure instead of an if statement? That way you can handle whatever error is produced by no route and move on to the next feature.

Comment: I've tried a try-except structure right now, I think it's what you meant with "catch". Tomorrow we will see if it's the right solution. Thanks

Comment: maybe the [`try-except-else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)-approach can help u

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
n=0
for f1 in layer1:
    p1 = f1.geometry().asPoint()
    x1, y1 = p1.x(), p1.y()
    coord1= f"{x1},{y1}"
     
    for f2 in layer2:
        p2 = f2.geometry().asPoint()
        x2, y2 = p2.x(), p2.y()
        coord2= f"{x2},{y2}"
        n += 1

        try:
            processing.run("native:shortestpathpointtopoint", {
                'INPUT':'./Do_Straßen_EPSG 25832.shp|layername=Do_Straßen_EPSG 25832',
                'STRATEGY':0,
                'DEFAULT_DIRECTION':2,
                'DEFAULT_SPEED':50,
                'TOLERANCE':0,
                'START_POINT':f"'{coord1}'", 
                'END_POINT':f"'{coord2}'",
                'OUTPUT':'./ShortPath/layer'+str(n)+'.shp'})
            
        except QgsProcessingException:
            print(f"There is no route from id_{f1.id()} to id_{f2.id()}.")
        except: # for other errors
            print(f"ERROR - id1:{f1.id()}, id2:{f2.id()}")
```

I removed unnecessary parts, like converting `coords` and `n` to string. No need to specify empty parameters in `processing.run`.